# SMTP Server Setup - Web Application

Tags: email, web-applications, smtp, telnet

I am having a few problems debugging an SMTP server connection when deploying a web application.

Basically, I have no control over the firewall or the SMTP server but have been given the details, whereas my web application errors every time saying -

```
Ex - Failure to send mail.
Inner Ex - Unable to connect to the remote server
```

I have installed telnet and attempted the following in command prompt -

```
telnet xxx.xxx.xx.xx 25
telnet <servername> 25
```

Neither of which work, they both return a message saying -

```
'could not open connection to host'
```

I can ping them SMTP server file from the server I am trying to install the web application on.

Does this mean it is a firewall issue? Or is there something else I am missing?

**I want to make absolutely sure I have my setup correctand have tested everything possible** before going back to the infrastructure guy...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the SMTP has been setup on port 25? is SMTP over SSL? Also is this a local server and a local app or is it external?

Comment: It is a server on the same network, I have been told it is port 25 and I am not sure if it is SSL.

Comment: in which case if it is on port 25 it could be over SSL but very much doubt it it should still connect. unless you have a firewall between your pc and the router this shouldn't be an issue as the firewall is normall between your gateway and server. Unless of cause the server itself is linux and iptables is blocking port 25

Comment: I have gone back to their infrastructure team to get them to check the firewall, I couldn't think of anything else that could be causing the issue. I have also tried taking the SMTP settings from another web application on another server (that works fine) and I get the same error.

Comment: hmm sounds bazar and the other application is running on a client machine? Does it have a static ip address? Can you use telnet to connect to port 80 on the server?

Comment: 2 different servers, 1 with my web application on, the other with a different web application (which also uses SMTP). I'll try telnet to 80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was 2 separate issues.

Firstly the firewall was blocking mail from the web server. Once this was resolved we found the second issue -

McAfee was blocking outbound emails, fix for this found [here](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/76D1CFA7F3C047D08625719B006861B5)